# How to intergrate hadoop using ambari without HDP?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I have a hadoop cluster with apache hadoop 2.0.7.

I want to know how to integrate Ambari with the apache hadoop without the HDP(HortonWorks).

Actually, If I use HDP the solution is easy. but , I don't want to use the  in my situation.

Do you have an any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambari relies on 'Stack' definitions to describe what services the Hadoop cluster consists of. Hortonworks defined a custom Ambari stack, its called HDP.

You could define your own stack and use any services and respective versions that you wanted. See the ambari wiki for more information about defining stacks and services.

That being said, I don't think it's possible to use your pre-existing installation of Hadoop with Ambari. Ambari is used to provision and manage hadoop clusters. It keeps track of the state of each of its stacks services, and the states of each services components. Since your cluster is already provisioned it would be difficult (maybe impossible) to add it to an Ambari instance.